# How to put the files of a folder in an array?

Tags: php

In a folder "images" I have a thousand xml files.Those filenames I want them to be insert into an array 
`$images = array('','');`

Instead of writing them all by hand, and this folder will be updated often, how can I do it automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` and `..` are always present in ALL directories ('current directory' and 'parent directory', respectively). You have to specifically filter them out. However, since you want only images, you could use something like `glob()` to just fetch images using regular shell wildcard patterns, e.g.

```
$files = glob('*.jpg');
```

which would give you all the files whose names end in `.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

Just exclude the `.` and `..` entries if you don't want them:

```
$files = array_diff( scandir($dir), array('.','..') );
```

Comment: When I set the files manually in an array, the script works. However with this it doesn't.

Comment: @mtopia: "Doesn't work" is kind of tough to debug.  What exactly are you doing, and what goes wrong with it?

Comment: OK, and what happens if you populate the array using the code I suggested?  (BTW, if your files always have an .xml suffix, you might as well just use Marc B's suggestion and do `glob("$dir/*.xml")`.)

Comment: @mtopia: Ah, I think I know what _might_ be the issue: the output of `scandir($dir)` only includes the file names.  You need to prefix them with `"$dir/"` yourself before passing them to anything that wants a full path to the file.